# How to explicitly declare field types for a graphql array

Tags: types, graphql

I am trying to figure out how to use graphql.

I have a model defined as follows.

```
model Request {
  id                     Int                       @id @default(autoincrement())
  skillCategories        SkillCategory[]

}
```

Then when I am trying to define the field types, I think I am following [this documentation](https://typegraphql.com/docs/0.17.2/types-and-fields.html) by specifying the array field type as follows:

```
import * as Prisma from "@prisma/client"
import { Field, ObjectType } from "type-graphql"

import { SkillCategory,  } from "@generated"


@ObjectType()
export class Request  implements Prisma.Request {
  
  
  
  @Field(() => [SkillCategory])
  skillCategories: Prisma.SkillCategory[];
 
}
```

Note: skillCategory is an enum defined in the schema.

I have also tried:

```
  @Field(type => [SkillCategory])
  skillCategories: Prisma.SkillCategory[];
```

When I try each of these variations, I get an error that says:

> NoExplicitTypeError: Unable to infer GraphQL type from TypeScript
> reflection system. You need to provide explicit type for
> 'skillCategories' of 'CreateRequest' class.

When I try expanding the input file syntax to expressly specify a type for the input type fields, I try this format:

@IsNotEmpty()
@Field(() => Agreement)
useTemplate: Agreement;

Agreement is imported from @generated as follows:

import { Agreement  } from "@generated"

When I try this, I get an error that says:

> CannotDetermineGraphQLTypeError: Cannot determine GraphQL output type
> for 'useTemplate' of 'Request' class. Is the value, that is used as
> its TS type or explicit type, decorated with a proper decorator or is
> it a proper output value?

Again, I can't make sense of this error message to find an idea about how to give the fields in the files a type that meets the expectation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is correct or if I'm just yet to find the error it creates, but to this point, I am able to create a record in the db by expressing arrays as follows. This isn't consistent with what's demonstrated in the prisma documentation - so I don't understand why this is correct.

```
@Field( () => [SkillCategory] )
skillCategories: SkillCategory[];
```